# How to use TextField as searchBar in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, searchbar

I want to use `textField` as `SearchBar` for my app. I followed the tutorial from [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_2HONmrR5Q) and I got the source code of the it at [github](https://github.com/leoiphonedev/AutocompleteSearch) . But unfortunately it is not working for my app. I can type text but it does not filters whatever I typed. My codes are below for your reference. Hope you can help me to solve my problem. Thank you so much.

```
var participants: [Attendee]!
var filteredParticipants = [Attendee]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ParticipantTableView.delegate = self
    ParticipantTableView.dataSource = self
    searchAttendeesTextField.delegate = self
    searchAttendeesTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(searchRecords(_ :)), for: .editingChanged)
}

//MARK:- UITextFieldDelegates

   func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    searchAttendeesTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

 //MARK: - searchRecords

   @objc func searchRecords(_ textField: UITextField) {
   self.filteredParticipants.removeAll()
    if textField.text?.count != 0 {

        for participant in participants {
            if let participantToSearch = textField.text{
                let range = participant.lastName.lowercased().range(of: participantToSearch, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil)
                if range != nil {
                    self.filteredParticipants.append(participant)
                }
            }
        }
    }else {
        for participant in participants {
            filteredParticipants.append(participant)

        }
    }
    ParticipantTableView.reloadData()

}

 // MARK: TABLE VIEW DATA SOURCE

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


      return participants.count
   }



  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FoldingCell")
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "FoldingCell")
    }
   // cell?.textLabel?.text = filteredParticipants[indexPath.row]
    return cell!
}
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? What does actually happen when you type? Is `searchRecords` being called at all? And you do realize that your table is based on `participants` and not `filteredParticipants`?

Comment: Use RXSwift and RXCocoa framework and enjoy.

Comment: Tip: _lowerCamelCase_ for variables names. `tableView` has another dequeue method which returns an instance if one is not available for reuse.

Comment: @rmaddy when I type, nothing happens.. It is like just typing in an empty textfield.

Comment: Make sure participants array isn't empty

Comment: @RajeshKumarR sorry I don't get it . I am totally new in using swift.

Comment: @RajeshKumarR data inside the tableView which is the participants are from an API

Comment: SearchBar is also textfield . Why dont you use search bar class for your needs ?

Comment: @AliIhsanURAL How? Actually I have a working searchbar, the default searchbar but the textfield height is to short for my liking that's why I decided to use textfield to customize the height and width.

Comment: I think your problem is in "range"

Comment: @AliIhsanURAL what about the range? What is the problem? please help me ... been debugging for almost two days :(

Answer (score 1):

Your `ParticipantTableView` data should be loaded with `filteredParticipants` array.

When you are adding the data in `participants` array at the same time add data in `filteredParticipants` array with all data and reload the `ParticipantTableView`.

Then in `tableview dataSource` methods:

```
// MARK: TABLE VIEW DATA SOURCE

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filteredParticipants .count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FoldingCell")
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "FoldingCell")
    }

    let attendeeSingleData = filteredParticipants[indexPath.row]
    cell?.textLabel?.text = attendeeSingleData."The data that you want to add"
    return cell!
}
```

`Attendee` must be a struct or class that you have created and you have to add data according the fields.

Don't remove data from `participants` array and keep changing the data as you are already doing in `filteredParticipants` array.

One more thing, your `tableView` name is `ParticipantTableView`, which is not good. Create methods with `lowerCamelCase` as `participantTableView`.

To know more you can go through this helpful URL:

- https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide

Answer (score -1):

Hello you need to use TextField Delegate methods for it.
You can use this one

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    //you will get here updated entered text
    print("TextField did begin editing method called", textField.text)
}
```